# WalletConnect + ethers.js signMessage is not working

Tags: ethers.js, walletconnect

I am trying to authenticate the ownership of a wallet using WalletConnect and ethers.js. I have already implemented the same code for MetaMask (browser extension) and it works fine. My problem is that when the message pops up for verification on the app (I have tried with TrustWallet and MetaMask mobile, same problem on both) it is an unreadable hex string. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/web3-provider";
import { providers } from "ethers";

const walletConnectProvider = new WalletConnectProvider({
infuraId: "REDACTED",
});

await walletConnectProvider.enable();

const provider = new providers.Web3Provider(walletConnectProvider);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
signature = await signer.signMessage(`I am signing my one-time nonce: ${nonce}`);
```

The `walletConnectProvider.enable()` line works fine, with the QR code popping up and being successfully scanned.

In addition, the signature never seems to be returned.